# How can I map JSON to object using enums for property names in Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, enums, mapping

I'm trying to map JSON data to an object using enums for property names. I currently receive object names in this format 'my.property.test' from the services. How can i use enums to map these names to my Object names?

```
{

   ‘my.propert1’: {
      'subprop1':'val',
      'subprop1':'val'
    },
   'my.propert2’: {
      'subprop1':'val',
      'subprop1':'val',
    }

}
```

My enum example:

```
enum propertyNames { 
   my.propert1, 
   my.propert2
}
```

Object to map to:

```
class MyObject {
    Property propert1,
    Property propert2
}
```

Fyi, I'm a noob and still trying to understand JSON => object mappings, especially in Dart.

Answer (score 1):

for parsing directly like in java ?? unfortunately no, but you can make a function like this to do it for you:-

```dart
ENUM mapAnEnum(String name) {
  for (var item in ENUM.values) {
            //addin toLowerCase() to just be sure but feel free to remove it !  
    if (item.toString().toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()) return item;
  }
}
```